# Drawing on canvas with python and tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, mouse-cursor

I am trying to display mouse position on timer. I use winfo_pointerxy(), here is part of the code from my_func():

```
curr_x, curr_y = mouseFrame.winfo_pointerxy()
curr_x = mouseFrame.canvasx(curr_x)
curr_y = mouseFrame.canvasy(curr_y)
mouseFrame.create_oval(curr_x, curr_y, curr_x + 5, curr_y + 5, fill='green')
start_btn.after(time_interval, my_func)
```

It seems like I use canvasx() wrong cause it still returns position counted from the left-up corner of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [tkinter reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-window-coords.html) (which I use constantly)

> Because the canvas may be larger than the window, and equipped with
>   scrollbars to move the overall canvas around in the window, there are
>   two coordinate systems for each canvas:
>
> ```
> The window coordinates of a point are relative to the top left
> corner of the area on the display where the canvas appears.
>
> The canvas coordinates of a point are relative to the top left
> corner of the total canvas.
> ```

If your canvas is against the upper left corner of the window (display) and you have not scrolled the canvas, the two sets of coordinates *should* be the same.